# Command line - Convert any string into an identifier?

Tags: bash

Often I'd like to be able to take a string at the command line (bash), and convert it into an identifier. Usually this is for use in a filename, branch name, or variable name, and I prefer that it:

- has no spaces in it
- has no special characters in it

So for example, I could take a string like so:

`bug fix for #PROJECT1 item 52, null pointer`

and convert it to something like this:

`bug_fix_for_PROJECT1_item_52__null_pointer`

I'm open to solutions in any language, e.g. bash, node, perl, python, etc, but prefer languages that are installed by default on most linux/osx machines.

Comment: There must be a dup. converting to an underscored filename? please search first.

Comment: Hey... I did search, but didn't find anything when searching. Regardless, this at the least will become a link to other solutions that are good for command line usage in bash!

Comment: :/ I see dozens of hits for `stackoverflow bash convert to filename underscore escape` or other meaningful combinations. my vote goes for: http://serverfault.com/questions/348482/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames

Comment: I get that - but I wasn't searching for what you were searching for.... I was searching for what i was searching for... "Command line - Convert any string into an identifier?".... I'm sure if we Google that now, this question will come up....

Comment: you should "accept" one of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an alternate variation in `perl` command-line substitution, to have exactly one `_` between words and *not* have consecutive characters like `__`

```
perl -ple 's/[^\w]/_/g;' -pe 's/__/_/g' <<<"bug fix for #PROJECT1 item 52, null pointer"
bug_fix_for_PROJECT1_item_52_null_pointer
```

and a simple snippet in `python` as

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+','_','bug fix for #PROJECT1 item 52, null pointer')
'bug_fix_for_PROJECT1_item_52_null_pointer'
```

Comment: Nice consideration on the "exactly one _"... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could so something like this :

```
original="bug fix for #PROJECT1 item 52, null pointer"
sanitized=${original//[^[:alnum:]]/_}
echo "$sanitized"
```

Le me break that down a bit :

- `${VAR_NAME//SEARCH/REPLACE}` searches and replaces all occurrences of `SEARCH` and performs the replacement.
- `[^[:alnum:]]` means any character that is NOT alphabetic or numeric.  The "NOT" part is the `^`
- The outer brackets indicate that the expression refers to one character chosen among the different possibilities listed inside the bracket (see below for how to use this to your advantage).

This could be tailored to do something a bit more subtle if desired.  Remember UNIX-like systems accept almost any character in file names (even newlines), so you are not restricted to letters and digits.

For instance, suppose you want to keep periods and commas in file names.  You could change the replacement statement :

```
sanitized=${original//[^[:alnum:].,]/_}
```

The modified part (`[^[:alnum:].,]`) means "anything that is not an alphanumeric character, and not a period, and not a comma".  You can add any other character you want to avoid replacing using regular expression syntax, but it is key that you keep the outer brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try tr?

```
echo 'bug fix for #PROJECT1 item 52, null pointer' |  tr -d [:punct:] | tr '[:blank:]' '_'

bug_fix_for_PROJECT1_item_52_null_pointer
```